# Indexing Calculated field in Sharepoint Online List

Tags: sharepoint-online

In my list, there is a Calculated Field which is being Set based on some conditions and another Calculated Field
So, now it has more than 5000 items and it will keep on increasing.
So, I have read that calculated fields cannot be Indexed but still wanted to know if there is any way through which I can Index my Calculated field or solve my Threshold Error.

Comment: There is not a way to create an index on Calculated column -- but depending on how you want to view the list, there are multiple options for working around the List View Threshold.  Are you trying to fix one or more views in the UI, or trying to access list items through API?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate columns is not supported for indexing: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-index-to-a-sharepoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0

[image]

To solve the list Threshold Error, you could:

- Use modern
- Add index on other supported columns
- Edit the list view

You could read this for more:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59

Answer (score 0):

I know this old post but adding info for future search,

As calculated column is not allowed to index, for all the scenario you can use the workaround of creation of text column and adding the power automate to set the value of it as per calculated formula.

So whenever new item is added or edited, that column will be updated and just create index on that column to resolve it.